# How to use autocomplete with python and Tkinter?

Tags: python, list, sqlite, tkinter, autocomplete

I am trying to select names from the `sqllite3` Database and then insert them into the list to use it with an autocomplete entry, so if the user types the first character in the `Entry(self.namesentry)` its automatically suggests the name if it is in the list.

Ex: google search when it suggests results Based on the data that's in it.

I have tried this:

```
def cardealersinfossql(self):
    self.con = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
    cardlearsinfosdb = (self.cardealenamevar.get(),self.cardealerlocationvar.get(),self.cardealerphonenumvar.get(),                                         self.cardealerphone2var.get())
                          

    self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()

   
    self.cursorObj.execute("""INSERT INTO cardealersinfos(dealername, 
dealerlocation, dealerphonenum1, dealerphonenum2)VALUES                          (?,?,?,?)""",cardlearsinfosdb)
       self.con.commit()

    # the list the is used with the AutoComplete Entry 
    self.con.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
    self.cardealenamelist = []
    for row in self.cursorObj.execute("select dealername from 
        cardealersinfos").fetchall():
        self.cardealenamelist.append(row[0])
        
def cardealersinfos(self):
    self.cardealerspage=Toplevel()
    self.cardealerspage.geometry("500x390+750+230")
 

    self.namesentry = AutocompleteEntry(self.cardealerspage,width=30,font=('Times', 
    18),completevalues=self.cardealenamelist )
    self.namesentry.place(x=80,y=253)


    self.cardlearinfoapplybtn = Button(self.cardealerspage, 
    text="apply",width=20,                                 
    height=2,fg='#FDFEFF',bg="#487FB9",command=self.cardealersinfossql)
    self.cardlearinfoapplybtn.place(x=175, y=320)

root = Tk()
x = Cardealer()

root.mainloop()
```

But it got this error:

```
self.namesentry = AutocompleteEntry(self.cardealerspage,width=30,font=('Times', 18),completevalues=self.cardealenamelist)
AttributeError: 'Cardealer' object has no attribute 'cardealenamelist'
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about an autocomplete entry, we don't need more than one example of that widget.  We don't need a bunch of other Button and Label widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok I will reduce it.

Comment: The problem is that `self.cardealerenamelist` is only created when `cardealersinfosslql()` is called. If it hasn't been called before you create `self.namesentry`, then you'll get this error message.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin aha ok, so what is the solution now?

Comment: I suggest that you put `self.cardealermaeslist = []` in your class's `__init__()` method. That should work.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin so if I create the list in the first root=Tk() if there any chance that its is will work?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin i tried this, is that what you mean?
class Cardealer():
    def __init__(self,cardealenamelist):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("1200x900+300+70")
        self.cardealenamelist=[]

Comment: Yes, something to that effect. You don't need `cardealenamelist` in the the parentheses unless you're planning to give a list as an argument, so you could also just use `class Cardealer(): def __init__(self):...`

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Thanks you man its worked